# How to specify start method in Powershell

Tags: powershell, script, variable

I have written a powershell script with couple of methods. I want to start powershell script with some specific method,for example the script should start with method `Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT()` How I specify in Script? Secondly, I have declared some global variables at start of script to use in methods. How methods will know about these variables for example how the function `Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT()` will know the value of variable `$Global:site`

Please correct method declaration if something wrong

```
$WepApp = "http://somesite.mysite.int/"
$Global:site = Get-SPSite $WepApp

Function Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT()
{
   $Global:site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | ForEach-Object { 
   $PagesLibrary = $_.Lists[$Global:lookForList]

    Remove-NewsPageCT $PagesLibrary $_
    }     
}

Function Remove-NewsPageCT($PagesLibrary,$web)
{
  # do some stuff here
  Add-NewsPageCT $PagesLibrary $count
}

Function Add-NewsPageCT($PagesLibrary,$count)
{
  # do some stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution of the script is from top to bottom. You have declare both of the variables at top, so they will get assigned with values.

After that you have defined few methods which makes use of it. During script execution these method definitions will not be executed unless they are called. Which I think is part of your question.

So to start or run the script. Refer below code update.

```
$WepApp = "http://somesite.mysite.int/"
$Global:site = Get-SPSite $WepApp

Function Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT()
{
$Global:site | Get-SPWeb -Limit all | ForEach-Object { 
$PagesLibrary = $_.Lists[$Global:lookForList]

    Remove-NewsPageCT $PagesLibrary $_
    }     
}

Function Remove-NewsPageCT($PagesLibrary,$web)
{
# do some stuff here
Add-NewsPageCT $PagesLibrary $count
}

Function Add-NewsPageCT($PagesLibrary,$count)
{
# do some stuff here
}


# Call function
#
Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT
```

By the time function `Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT` is getting executed the global varidable `$Global:site` will have value in it.

**Update**:

This blog [How To Make Use Of Functions in PowerShell](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2015/01/how-to-make-use-of-functions-in-powershell.html) has good examples to run functions read the 3rd option, that's what I have explained

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your question is related to SharePoint, but I usually write like this (good old `main(argc,argv)` C-style single entry point):

```
$main = {
    <call to Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT>
}

function Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT() {
    <some code>
}

& $main
```

[Mr. Wilson](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/) is the best source of Powershell how to's

Comment: Aziz and Asad: I tried both ways you mentioned: but i got error: Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT : The term 'Get-SitesWithNewsPageCT' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.---- But when i run the script for second time it did not give any error and seems to work??

Comment: @SPBeginer So what was the difference you had while running the script second time?

Comment: @SPBeginer There can be one thing. If you try to call function before its definition then you get such error. The rule is that function must be defined first then call it.

Comment: @SPBeginer Please try @AsadRefai 's edited script. The idea is to put functions in reverse order of how they are called. If `function A` calls `function B`, then put `function B` earlier in the script. But I prefer single entry point structure when `main` is the first thing you see in file and `& $main` is the last.